# HoloViz, Panel. DateRangeSlider or DateSlider: how can I change the step to hours instead of days?

Tags: widget, bokeh, panel, holoviews, holoviz

With the following code:

```
pn.extension(sizing_mode='stretch_width')
start=df.index[0]
end = df.index[-1]
time_slider = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(value=(start,end), name='Fecha', start=start, end=end, format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
time_slider
```

I get this Time Slider:
[TimeSlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtVKa.jpg)

Is there any formatting tool so I can change the step from days to hours?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

dateslider don't have an option to change hours. but you could add a regular slider and add only hours to that slider to change.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with EditableRangeSlider or RangeSlider widgets, heres an example:

```
time_slider = pn.widgets.EditableRangeSlider(name='Hora', format=['%Hh', '%H:%M'], start='00:00', end='23:59')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I've tried with EditableRangeSlider and with RangeSlider, but it gives me a ValueError: 

""ValueError: ClassSelector parameter 'format' value must be an instance of (str, TickFormatter), not ['%Hh', '%H:%M']""